# packaged ECONNREFUSED/unpackaged ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: failing to get app runing on lg web os simulator

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, webos, lg

```
felixolszewski@Felixs-MacBook-Pro-2 SMART TV % ares-install --device emulator "/Users/felixolszewski/Desktop/SMART TV/com.felixolszewski.app1_1.0.0_all.ipk"        
ares-install ERR! [syscall failure]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6622
ares-install ERR! [Tips]: Connection refused. Please check the device IP address or the port number

felixolszewski@Felixs-MacBook-Pro-2 SMART TV % ares-setup-device --list                                                                                                          
name                deviceinfo                connection  profile
------------------  ------------------------  ----------  -------
emulator (default)  developer@127.0.0.1:6622  ssh         tv     

felixolszewski@Felixs-MacBook-Pro-2 SMART TV %
```

Do I need to link my simulator manually? Or does the emulator device in the list refer to the simulator? If manually: how exactly? I would have no clue what to set as:

1. name
2. deviceinfo
3. ssh
4. tv

Why do I want to execute this command?

I want to create an app from a static Angular15 website. I also tried simply opening the unpackaged app build folder, as shown in the lg web os tutorial: https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/getting-started/build-your-first-web-app

But then I got this error when inspecting my app:
[image]

FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, for those four filenames:

1. runtimemefa9a14c71368959.js:1
2. polyfillssc5a6162cac4767e2mjs:1
3. main.607e420b5eadbc63.js:1
4. styles.56a9653a72393d06scss:1

Hence I tried deploying the packaged app, as this might resolve the error. But maybe I also have to be able to launch my unpackaged app? If so, then why am I getting the error? I think it could be related to:
https://forum.webostv.developer.lge.com/t/failed-to-load-module-script-error-on-webos-5-lg-tvs/2351

Can anyone help? I am not too familiar with specifc js/es version things. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./cypress.config.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "cypress"
  ]
}
```